# Multiply recycler view and adapters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually I am going to ask more than one question here. Don't ban me, please, just read a full story. Let's begin. So I need to create an activity or fragment (it doesn't matter) with to parts (views) inside (top and bottom). Inside the bottom part dynamically loads buttons (sometimes 2, sometimes 30), there is a click listener on them. When a user clicks on a button, the button appears on the top part (view) and disappears on the bottom view. The buttons on the top view also have click listener and if a user clicks on a button it appears on the bottom view and disappears on a top. So this is a task. I thought how to implement it. The simplest solution that I created is: two views are recycler views with two adapters. Mm, probably it is not the best solution, I am pretty sure of it. I could implement two adapters, but I can't implement the click listener for my second adapter. It doesn't work!? I don't like this way for two reasons: 1. both adapters are the same; 2. I can't use click adapter for second adapter. Below you can find my code.
My adapter - standard adapter:

```
    public class KeyboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KeyboardAdapter.KeyboardAdapterViewHolder> {
    private List<String> values;

    /*
     * An on-click handler that we've defined to make it easy for an Activity to interface with
     * our RecyclerView
     */
    private final KeyboardAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    /**
     * The interface that receives onClick messages.
     */
    public interface KeyboardAdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onClick(int position, String nameClicked);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a SourceAdapter.
     *
     * @param clickHandler The on-click handler for this adapter. This single handler is called
     *                     when an item is clicked.
     */
    public KeyboardAdapter(List<String> myDataset, KeyboardAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        values = myDataset;
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Cache of the children views for a forecast list item.
     */
    public class KeyboardAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        // each data item is just a string in this case
        private Button btnValue;
        private String mName;
        public View layout;
        private int parentId;

        private KeyboardAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //layout = view;
            btnValue = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

            //parentId = ((View) btnValue.getParent()).getId();

            // Call setOnClickListener on the view passed into the constructor (use 'this' as the OnClickListener)
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setData(String name) {
            mName = name;
            btnValue.setText(mName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            mClickHandler.onClick(adapterPosition, mName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public KeyboardAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        return new KeyboardAdapterViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull KeyboardAdapterViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.setData(values.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        values.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, values.size());
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

    String s = "test it";

    mAdapter = new KeyboardAdapter(virtualKeyboardInit(s), MainActivity.this);

    recyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // empty list just to init rv
    answerList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    mAdapter1 = new KeyboardAdapter1(answerList, MainActivity.this); // doesn't work, error message "KeyboardAdapter1.KeyboardAdapterOnClickHandler cannot be applied to MainActivity"

    recyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
}

private List<String> virtualKeyboardInit(String s) {
    boolean checkBool = true;

    // convert string to array and then to list
    String [] strArray = s.split("(?!^)");
    stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
    // shuffle letters in the list
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(stringList, new Random(seed));
    // API 24
    // /String[] strArray = Stream.of(cArray).toArray(String[]::new);
    return stringList;
}

@Override
public void onClick(int position, String nameClicked) {
    mAdapter.remove(position);
}
```

These are just a fragment of code. So, what can I do in this case? Thank you for attention and help.

Comment: set `clickListner`  in OnBindView Directly on the view or you can use  RecyclerView `clickListener`.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try it ))